# How to load a firebase admin key in node js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-admin

I want to use the firebase admin SDK to give my node server free access to my database. This is the code of `index.js` in my `functions` folder:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Initialize app
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("logininfo.json"),
  databaseURL: "https://thenameofmydatabase.firebaseio.com/",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "nameserver"
  }
});
```

In the same folder, I have my logininfo.json, which looks something like this (censored the keys for obvious reasons):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "...",
  "client_email": "...",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
}
```

However, I get the error `Failed to parse certificate key file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory` when trying to deploy to firebase hosting.

How do I fix this and is there a more secure / elegant way to handle this? Can I just change the [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) variable somewhere in firebase hosting?

Comment: Use `.env` files. Remember not to commit these files.

Comment: What exactly are you doing to deploy this?  What is your project structure?  Can you read the config file directly with your own code?  How exactly can we reproduce this ourselves?

Comment: @SumitRidhal thanks, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @DougStevenson I use firebase hosting for my website. The config file is just the private key file generated through [google service accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk).

Comment: Firebase Hosting doesn't run node apps.  It just serves static content.  If you want to run node routes behind Firebase Hosting, you'll need to integrate with Cloud Functions.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Comment: @Doug I got my functions folder through `firebase init functions`. `nameserver` also shows up under my functions in the firebase dashboard. Isn't this what you mean?

Comment: When working with Cloud Functions, you don't need to provide a service account.  You can use the default service account for project, which is used if you initialize the Admin SDK with no arguments.  `admin.initializeApp()` - this is the most common thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done by 2 different ways:

**By Path:**

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    const serviceAccount = require("path/to/logininfo.json");

    // Initialize app
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://thenameofmydatabase.firebaseio.com/",
      databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
        uid: "nameserver"
      }
    });
```

**By Object:**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
        const admin = require("firebase-admin");

        // Initialize app
        admin.initializeApp({
          credential: admin.credential.cert({
               "type": "service_account",
               "project_id": "...",
               "private_key_id": "...",
               "private_key": "...",
               "client_email": "...",
               "client_id": "...",
               "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
               "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
               "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
               "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
               "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
        }),
          databaseURL: "https://thenameofmydatabase.firebaseio.com/",
          databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
            uid: "nameserver"
          }
        });
```

Comment: By path, I get the `Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'logininfo.env'`

Comment: Please share, how you are providing path

Comment: Like so `const serviceAccount = require("logininfo.json");`, because logininfo.json and the javascript file are in the same folder.

Comment: Try

const serviceAccount = require("./logininfo.json");

Comment: i donno, but i tried to move the `servie_account.json` file up to `lib` directory with the normal relative path `("./service_account.json")` it worked!!!. so strange.